# Edit my question when I have the answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-answer

Yesterday I asked a question that was marked as a duplicate and I don't understand why because neither of the suggested questions helped me. But one of the comments helped me in the right direction and I finally found the solution. Now I would like to answer my own question for the benefit of others.

The answer box is gone, I guess because of the duplicate-mark. Should I now:

1. Edit the question to include the answer
2. Post a new question with the answer (more like a tutorial)
3. Make a tutorial somewhere else (please suggest where if you know of a great place)
4. Forget about it

I rather not do 4, because I would like to help anybody else with the same problem (and that might not have the skills to use the right terms to search for an answer, like I did before I got the useful comment). But I have not been here enough to now what's appropriate here, and I didn't find an answer in the FAQ or elsewhere.

I hope some of you more experienced users might take the time to just comment with the number of your preferred option (1-4). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you can answer your own questions. That's encouraged. But to do so, write an actual answer, do not include it in the question itself.

In your special case, you have some options:

1. If you believe that your question wasn't actually a duplicate, edit it to include a section on why it's not a duplicate of the other questions. You could also take it to the respective meta site and ask there, why it was closed (and if it can be reopened).
2. As it was marked a duplicate, if one of the other questions is still answerable and your solution answers that question, write an answer there.

<sub>Yes, you can't write an answer to a question *closed* as a duplicate.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I'm not allowed to post in the meta, so I did your second suggestion, tried to choose the question most like mine.